# Django Mysql Complex annotations require an alias

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use variable as filter key value. All variables take exact values i want but then i get this error. here is my view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def map_data(request):
    query_id = request.POST.get('queryId', 1)
    group_name = request.POST.get('group', 'district')
    query = QueryList.objects.using('teldata').get(query_id=query_id)
    groups = query.network_element.lower().split(',')
    values = query.kpi_val.lower().split(',')
    kwargs = {groups[0]: group_name}

    if len(values) == 1:
        if len(groups) == 1:
            report_data = SiteData.objects.using('teldata').values(groups[0]).annotate(
                'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id', Avg(values[0])
            ).filter(**kwargs)
        elif len(groups) == 2:
            report_data = SiteData.objects.using('teldata').values(groups[0], groups[1]).annotate(
                'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id', Avg(values[0])
            ).filter(**kwargs)
    elif len(values) == 2:
        if len(groups) == 1:
            report_data = SiteData.objects.using('teldata').values(groups[0]).annotate(
                'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id', Avg(values[0]), Avg(values[1])
            ).filter(**kwargs)
        elif len(groups) == 2:
            report_data = SiteData.objects.using('teldata').values(groups[0], groups[1]).annotate(
                'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id', Avg(values[0]), Avg(values[1])
            ).filter(**kwargs)
    return Response(report_data)
```

error log is below:

```
Complex annotations require an alias
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5555/data/map-data/
Django Version: 1.9.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Complex annotations require an alias
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in annotate, line 895
Python Executable:  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/hco/PycharmProjects/tool/linyit',
 '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/hco/PycharmProjects/tool',
 '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

mainly i want to add a dynamic filter that can change according to request parameters. if you suggest any other way i am open it also. thanks

Comment: notsure I can see the error here?

Comment: @Barry I added the error

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complex annotation.

```
.annotate(
      'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id'
      ,Avg(values[0]))
```

This ORM query will be converted to an SQL query that includes a group by clause. Typically the ORM will group by one of the keys and aggregate on the `values[0]` field (whatever that is). But what about the other fields `latitude`, `longitude` etc? You don't have any grouping or aggregations for them and that confuses the query parser.

If you take a moment to think about this query a bit, you will realize that fetching `long_call_id` while you are grouping on a particular column doesn't really have any meaning. YIn fact old versions of mysql (prior to 5.7.6) would ch

Answer (score 0):

i found my error and it was a bad mistake:

the working code is below:

```
report_data = SiteData.objects.using('teldata').filter(**kwargs).values(
            'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id', groups[0]).annotate(Avg(values[0]))
```

'latitude', 'longitude', 'latt_call_id', 'long_call_id' should be in values part in all instances.